# No funciona el Intent, creo que el problema lo tengo en el Manifest

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando una página para que el usuario pueda registrarse. Una vez hecho, le das al botón Registrar y si todo está bien te lleva a la siguiente página que es MainActivity.java. El problema es que siempre me sale el Toast, y no sé porqué no funciona como debería. Alguien me puede indicar que es lo que tengo mal en mi código?

No estoy seguro, pero creo que puede que el problema esté en mi Manifest. Entiendo que es algo sencillo, pero algo estoy pasando por alto y no sé lo que es. A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

Gracias de antemano.

**RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText mUsername, mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mButtonRegister;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mButtonRegister = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txt_username = mUsername.getText().toString();
                String txt_email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String txt_password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (txt_password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password must contain at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    register(txt_username, txt_email, txt_password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void register(final String username, final String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                    mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("id", userid);
                    hashMap.put("username", username);
                    hashMap.put("imageURL", "default");

                    mReference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register with that email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.e.chatapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: En realidad te sugiero revisar el LogCat lo que sucede es el listener no esta obteniendo una respuesta correcta, agrega que mensaje se muestra.

Answer (score 0):

mira amigo la verdad tengo demasiado tiempo que no uso Android y no se si esto te llegue a servir pero recuerdo que para poder enviar o recibir datos necesitas agregar permisos de conexión en el Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

con eso habilitas el acceso a Internet y permitir la trasferencia de datos.Espero y te sirva y te ayude en algo.

Comment: No me ha servido agregar lo que me has dicho. Es que directamente me sale el Toast en lugar de llevarme a la siguiente página que es el MainActivity. Por qué sale el Toast en lugar de que se graben los datos en Firebase y se cree un nuevo usuario...

Comment: Esto no es el problema, el problema es que la tarea no se esta realizando, pueden ser muchas otras causas.